# Extracting ONLY number values between specific characters while ignoring string-number combination

Tags: c#, regex

I have for example this string,

```
|SomeText1|123|0#$0#62|SomeText2|456|6#83|SomeText3#61|SomeText1#41|SomeText5#62|SomeText3#82|SomeText9#40|SomeText2#$1#166|SomeText2|999|7#146|SomeText2#167|SomeText2#166|
```

I want to extract only number values and add them to list and later sum them. That means values,

`|123|,|456|, |999|`.

All other values like,

`|SomeText1|,|SomeText2|,|SomeText2#$1#166|`

shouldn't be in list.

I'm working with C#. I tried something like,

```
int sum = 0;

List<int> results = new List<int>();

Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\|(.*?)\|");
Match matchResults = regexObj.Match(s);
while (matchResults.Success)
{
    results.Add(Convert.ToInt32(matchResults));
    matchResults = matchResults.NextMatch();
}

for (int i = 0; i < results.Count; i++)
{
    int bonusValues = results[i];
    sum = sum + bonusValues;
}
```

So basic idea is to extract values between `| |` characters and ignore one that are not pure digits like

`|#16543TextBL#aBLa564B|`

Comment: Replace `(.*?)` in your regex with `(\d+)`?

Comment: if you don't need specific the regex stuff you could easily split the string with: 
      
    string[] splits = s.split('|'); 

then you could loop through this set of strings and try to parse it to an integer. I

for(int i=0; i<splits.size(); i++){
    bool isNum = double.TryParse(Str, out Num);
}
if (isNum)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if you don't need specific the regex stuff you could easily split the string with:

```
string[] splits = s.split('|');
```

then you could loop through this set of strings and try to parse it to an integer. I

```
for(int i=0; i<splits.size(); i++){
  int num;
  bool isNum = int.TryParse(splits[i], out num);
  if(isNum){
   list.add(num);
  }
}
```

Comment: 1) `split` => `Split` 2) `add` => `Add` 3) `size()` => `Length` 4) Str?

Answer (score 2):

```
string input = @"|SomeText1|123|0#$0#62|SomeText2|456|6#83|SomeText3#61|SomeText1#41|SomeText5#62|SomeText3#82|SomeText9#40|SomeText2#$1#166|SomeText2|999|7#146|SomeText2#167|SomeText2#166|";

var numbers = Regex.Matches(input, @"\|(\d+)\|")
                   .Cast<Match>()
                   .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value).ToList();

var sum = numbers.Sum(n => int.Parse(n));
```

Answer (score 1):

If regex isn't a definite requirement, you could use linq

```
stringName.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Where(x => x.All(char.IsNumber)).ToList();
```

---

With sum

```
stringName.Split("|".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
          .Where(x => x.All(char.IsNumber)).Sum(x => int.Parse(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to tried below menioned code

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"\d+");
```

\d represents any digit, + for one or more. 
If you want to catch negative numbers as well you can use -?\d+.

```
Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"-?\d+");
```

Note that as a string, it should be represented in C# as "\d+", or @"\d+"